# Ink drawing on school notebook art style name

Tags: style-identification, style, graphic-styles, ink

I am not graphic designer and this is my fist question on this site and sorry if I won't be clear enough or it's not fully related to this portal.

There are lot's of art styles e.g pixel art and so on and I am asking this question because I want to find out what is name of style of art which is used in mobile game [Sea Battle](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.byril.seabattle&hl=en) and [Sea Battle 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.byril.seabattle2&hl=en). Here are the image for more details.

[image]

The reason I am asking this question is that I want to find some free assets in the internet. I am not digital artist myself so I cant draw anything. Can you suggest me how would you google that?

Comment: Hi Chestera and welcome to GDSE. Your question is clear enough, but I don't know how to answer it. I don't see it as a *style* as such but more as a *medium*. Isn't it just drawing with a blue ballpoint pen on checkered paper? Couldn't the style differ from artist to artist? Why doesn't it work for you to just take a blue ballpoint pen and draw on checkered paper?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your respond
The reason I am asking this question is that I wanna google it to find some free assets in the internet. I am not digital artist myself so I cant draw anything. Can you suggest me how would you google that?

Comment: I dunno ... something like [blue ballpoint pen drawing on checkered paper](https://www.google.com/search?q=blue+ballpoint+pen+drawing+on+checkered+paper&tbm=isch)? But I'm afraid it might be hard to find something very specific drawn this way for free.

Comment: Okay, as I guess best way to search is "ballpoint pen" keyword. Thank you very much, it helped me

Comment: There is even article on wikipedia btw
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballpoint_pen_artwork

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you search for pencil drawings and study how to recolor them & add the right background paper image in graphic software you'll have more options than by searching fully ready results. There's no need to shell out money for programs. Freebies such as Paint.NET and GIMP can both do the recoloring. Inkscape is useful for your own vector drawings, but not a must. I guess in a week you can do the modifications by yourself and nothing prevents you to ask help. It's our hobby.

I guess high quality drawings generally aren't free.

This is an example of the recoloring:

[image]

It's made of 2 images which both were black or grey on white. There are 2 layers, the top layer (=boat) has got a little different recoloring than the bottom layer. The white areas in the boat image are selected and deleted to make the grid visible. The image is copied from this wikihow article: https://www.wikihow.com/Draw-a-Boat

I guess nearly any drawing with visible pen texture will do the job if the subject is the wanted one and you recolor it to ballpoint-pen color. Even some simple enough photos which are filtered to have drawing like texture and single color can be plausible enough

Comment: Okay, I'll try it in Paint.NET, It's my favorite editing freeware. Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 1):

Those are typically called [pen and ink drawings](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=pen+and+ink+drawing&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwj8z5bxu73oAhWWBGMBHRVrADYQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=pen+and+ink+drawing&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIECAAQQzIECAAQQzICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAOgQIIxAnUMOBCliEiQpgoY8KaABwAHgAgAF1iAGABpIBAzYuMpgBAKABAaoBC2d3cy13aXotaW1n&sclient=img&ei=-2p_XrzmBJaJjLsPldaBsAM&bih=916&biw=1920).  The colour of the ink is irrelevant. The paper is called "graph paper", which also has nothing to do with this style of illustration.

Comment: I think pen and ink drawings have a slightly different expression than ballpoint drawings. Pen and ink drawings normally have the same solid tone in all lines, but with different line weights whereas ballpoint drawings have the same line width but can be darker when you push harder or draw several times on the same spot.

Comment: @Wolff - I agree. However I don't think it's possible to tell what kind of pen the OP's example images were drawn with. They're not really detailed enough to tell. They could even have been drawn digitally and coloured blue for all I know.  I mean "pen and ink drawings" in a very general sense, as this is what they are typically called in English, regardless of the type of pen used.